# A-Frame AR.js custom AR marker not working

Tags: aframe

I've read through lots of posts, including this very thorough and long one at https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/164, as well as https://medium.com/chialab-open-source/ar-js-the-simpliest-way-to-get-cross-browser-ar-on-the-web-8f670dd45462. But still, I cannot get my custom marker working.

I've designed it 16*16, uploaded in https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html , but again, nothing shows up except the hiro and kanji presets...

My code is as followed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<!-- Marker-based AR -->
  <!-- NOTE: Cannot work on local server -->
  <!-- NOTE: multiple a-marker-camera can work at the same time, but if the object is defiend outside, they can appear on one marker at a time -->
  <!-- AR.js by @jerome_etienne - github: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/ar.js - info: https://medium.com/arjs/augmented-reality-in-10-lines-of-html-4e193ea9fdbf -->
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/examples/vendor/aframe/build/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false'>
        <a-sphere position="0 0.5 0" radius="0.5" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
        <a-plane position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" width="1" height="1" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
        <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
      <a-marker-camera type="pattern" url="Markers_AR/pattern-Simple.patt"></a-marker-camera>
      <a-marker-camera type="pattern" url="Markers_AR/pattern-Simple2.patt"></a-marker-camera>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any helps would be very appreciated!

Comment: My repository is at https://github.com/neilzhu2/neilzhu2.github.io, where you can find the custom image I used in folder Markers_AR, the simple.jpg is the 16*16 image I uploaded, pattern-Simple.patt and pattern-Simple2.patt are generated by the marker trainer, and I used pattern-simple.jpt for detecting.

Answer (score 0):

yes just change the reference script to the 1.5.5 version. Then all solve

source: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/216